# How to exit QApplication from another thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qml

So the problem is that in any application sometimes the GUI might freeze. Regardless of why it has happened, I want to be able to terminate/exit/quit my application.
Is there any way to do it from another thread (in the same application instance)? Assume that the GUI event loop is frozen and stuck in a `while(1);` line for example!

What I've already tried:
Calling QCoreApplication::quit() on qApp from another thread, which doesn't work because the GUI event loop is blocked.
Calling QCoreApplication::exit() on qApp from another thread, which doesn't work because it says I can only call it from the GUI thread.

If it is not possible to do it from another thread, how would you suggest to exit the application, assuming the GUI thread is blocked?

Comment: The 'real' problem here is the GUI thread becoming unresponsive.  You should fix that rather than trying to patch things up by forcing an exit.

Comment: @G.M. True, but that is still no reason for me to not learn how to do it. If it was really unnecessary, the cpp standard wouldn't have implemented std::abort, as stated in the answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you want a hard or a graceful exit? For a super hard exit, that can't be blocked by shutdown handlers (destructors, functions registered with `atexit`) use the C standard function `abort`: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/abort

Comment: `std::exit(int returnCode)` with normal (graceful) exit was enough! thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

It’s customary to use a separate watchdog application for that instead. It should regularly ping your application, and if that fails, kill it and restart it. Doing it from within the application itself doesn’t sound very reliable.

Comment: AFAIK using another thread does the exact same thing, right? I don't see why I would need to run another application for that. But the process is still the same as you have described.